# How to get bigram in spacy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I am using this code

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Cloud computing is benefiting major manufacturing companies")
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(chunk.text)
```

This is the output:

```
Cloud computing
major manufacturing companies
```

The second line has 3 words, I only want 2. What should I do?

Comment: Which 2 words do you want/expect?

Comment: See this link: https://spacy.io/api/textcategorizer#architectures